How to make nohup release prompt?
The script below never prints done unless you manually hit the enter key. The dev machine is osx, the server ubuntu 22.04.
It's a script to restart the remote web server. Web server uses bun.js javascript server, the remote command first kills any bun process, and then starts server with nohup.
function remote() {
  ssh -l root -p $PORT $HOST "source ~/.bash_profile && $1"
}

echo "  restarting server"
remote "killall -r bun || true && nohup /apps/run_server.ts > /logs/server.txt 2>&1 < /dev/null &"
echo "  done"

The /apps/run_server.ts content, a javascript (typescript) code with shebang:
#!/usr/bin/env bun

import 'my_server'
run_myserver()


& applies to the whole line, including the killall command. Try to put nohup in a subshell
.. && (nohup /apps/run_server.ts > /logs/server.txt 2>&1 < /dev/null &)

